# Add elements to array without duplicates MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to add elements to the array of objects. This works to "add" but if user 1 has the book in their array user 1 can keep adding it again however if user 2 has it in their array then user 1 cant add it at all.
Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
uid: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
//Array of books that user has added to their list.
//MongoDb will return this for the user on their profile
myList: [
    {
    bookId: {type: String, required: true},
    bookImage: {type: String, required: true},
    bookTitle: {type: String, required: true},
}]
```

}, {timestamps: true})

Function I am trying

```
try {
const response = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'uid': uid },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      myList:
      {
        'bookId': req.body.book.id,
        'bookImage': req.body.book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
        'bookTitle': req.body.book.volumeInfo.title,
      }

    }
  })
console.log('Added', response)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To prevent array duplicates in the same collection, you can create unique multikey indexes on that collection. MongoDB will return an error when there's an identical array been inserted or updated. Here's the command you can run on the mongo shell.

```
db.users.createIndex({myList:1},{unique:true})
```

[Official Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)
[Mongoose Indexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)